# Why is es6-iterator test folder copying itself multiple times?

Tags: node-modules

For some reason the test folder under

```
es6-iterator/#/test
```

keeps copying all scripts and folders into another test folder.  So the directory looks like this:

```
es6-iterator/#test/test/test/test/test/test...
```

Can someone please tell me what could be causing this?